# How do I implement a contacts search function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

I'm trying to create a contacts search function for my project but I'm having a bit of trouble trying to solve it. The function contains 3 parameters:
firstname: user first name (string)
lastname: user last name (string)
searchInput: current text input that the user is searching (string)

it should return true if user is found. If not, return false.

for example:

```
contactsSearchfilter("John", "Doe", "jo") = true
contactsSearchfilter("John", "Doe", "do") = true
contactsSearchfilter("John", "doe", "John doe") = true
contactsSearchfilter("John", "doe", "john Doe") = true
contactsSearchfilter("John", "doe", "") = true
contactsSearchfilter("John", "doe", "john Doe asdf") = false
contactsSearchfilter("John", "doe", "ohn") = false
contactsSearchfilter("John", "doe", "asdf") = false
```

contactsSearchFilter:

```
function contactsSearchFilter(firstname, lastname, searchInput) {
   
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems you might be interested in [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: A simple regex in form of **new RegExp(````.*${firstName}.*${lastName}.*````,'i')** should work